# How can I find all nested Components using React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am looking to validate a form with Redux. I am trying to use make a form component which will iterate through children and find various input components (not to be confused with a native `<input>`.

I know there are a lot of open source solutions, but I'd like to understand some mechanics before jumping into picking any. I have a Form component setup to test like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._iterate(this.props.children);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</form>
    );
  }

  _iterate(children) {
    React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
      console.log(child);
      if (child.props.children) {
        console.log('get children');
        this._iterate(child.props.children);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I then have another Component with a render like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form>
        <ComponentA />
        <ComponentB />
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now `ComponentA` or `ComponentB` might have a component that nests more components down the line. Within those components would be a React component I have made for Text, Select, etc.

The code above would just console.log the components, and any children of them, that are in this specific render. It does not jump down into `ComponentA` children.

Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem you really want to solve.

The power in react is largely around the design pattern it encourages, and what you're doing is breaking that pattern;  Component's should only talk to their immediate children and respond to their immediate parents.  If you need to go deeper than that, then the component in the middle needs to be responsible for passing that data.

Rather than trying to dig into the innards of ComponentA and ComponentB, those component's themselves should have the accessibility props that you need.  I.e., `<ComponentA onChange={whatever} errorMessage={whatever}/>` etc. and then hooking those props to their children should occur within ComponentA.

Comment: That would imply for each level of nesting, I must pass a callback through. So if a form is on one level, and input is 3 components down, I'd need to keep passing the callbacks through?

Comment: That's correct.  This is a big reason behind React pushing for use of the spread operator.  If there are multiple items you want to keep passing down the chain, you can just pass the entire props along i.e. <ChildComponent {...this.props}/>

Comment: Yeah I do love that spread operator. I'll play with that. But also I'm using Redux so I feel like I can get a win with reducers and dispatches.

Comment: Welllll....  Feel free to use the tools at your disposal however you see fit, but you should be aware that most flux architecutres (including redux) suggest only interacting with the stores via a top-level "Container" component, which (you guessed it) passes those values down the chain to it's great great great grandchildren.

Comment: I had heard about this months ago. But I was talking to folks around, including IRC, and they said connecting only at the top wasn't the definitive best practice anymore.

Comment: I completely agree, but it's a good idea to be cautious when breaking any design pattern, even if it's not used 100% of the time.

Comment: Sounds good Jake. How would you provide functionality to a button that is inside our Header component, which mutes all video and audio components in our website when clicked? A global mute/unmute so to say.

Comment: @rmartrenado:  Flux is the typical design pattern for global state.  Redux is the most popular library that implements it.  Have a button update that global state, and then allow other components to use that global state to control their behavior.